# IOS - Resize width masterview in uisplitview using storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uisplitview

I don't know how to change width masterview in splitview, now this is fix width 320px, I wanna resize down width 100 or 200px, I wonder how to change this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You've got to use custom `SplitViewController`, because you cannot change the width of standart layout. You can:

- Follow [this tutorial](http://mlk-ios-programming-concepts.blogspot.ru/2013/05/custom-split-view-for-ios.html),
- Use [this library](https://github.com/percysnoodle/SGBDrillDownController),
- Or [this one](https://github.com/luka1995/LPThreeSplitViewController).

Comment: thank you for answer, but i'm using storyboard, XIB is very old performance. Can you have a difference solution